# AWS-CLI: Ways to list down autoscalinggroups

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, autoscaling

Is there a way to list down the available AutoScalingGroups under an account and filter on top of it based on some tags?
I am looking for something like `aws ecs list-clusters` which gives list of ecs clusters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. You can use [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/) syntax to filter the results of `aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups` command down to only those groups matching some tag's key/value pair. This uses the `--query` parameter, which is available for filtering on most AWS CLI commands.

**Example to query by a single tag:**

The example below filters results based on a tag where Key = 'Environment' and Value = 'Dev'.

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query "AutoScalingGroups[? Tags[? (Key=='Environment') && Value=='Dev']]".AutoScalingGroupName
```

**Example to query by multiple tags:**

The example below filters results based on tags where Key = 'Environment' and Value = 'Dev', and Key = 'Name' and Value = 'MyValue'. This uses a pipe to query for the second tag on the resulting autoscaling groups of the query for the first tag.

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query "AutoScalingGroups[? Tags[? (Key=='Environment') && Value=='Dev']] | [? Tags[? Key=='Name' && Value =='MyValue']]".AutoScalingGroupName
```

### Further Reading

- [AWS Documentation - aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-auto-scaling-groups.html)
- [AWS Documentation - Controlling Command Output from the AWS Command Line Interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. Can you plz let me know how can we pass multiple tags to the query argument?

Comment: I got it to work by using a pipe operator to filter it based on another tag.

Comment: @A.K.Desai Nice, I was updating with the same just as you commented.  Answer is updated with an example, for future readers.

Comment: Thanks again @Anthony.

Comment: This is incorrect answer.  `--query` is a client side option.  If you have a lot of ASGs you can get paginated out.  `--filters` on the other hand performs the query server side.

Answer (score 2):

The below AWS CLI command gives Auto Scaling Group with Tag having `Key` == `Product` and `Value` == `test` for a profile of account1

```
aws --profile account1 autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups \
--query 'AutoScalingGroups[?contains(Tags[?Key==`Product`].Value, `test`)].[AutoScalingGroupName]' --region eu-west-1 --output table
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation as to why this is a solution to OP's problem. Code only answers are discouraged on SO as they do not help OP or future visitors of the site.

Comment: @d_kennetz just added Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups \
  --query AutoScalingGroups[].AutoScalingGroupName \
  --filters \
  "Name=tag:MyTagKey1,Values=MyTagValue1" \
  "Name=tag:MyTagKey2,Values=MyTagValue2"
```